# Enviar jwt no header por GET

Tags: node.js, react, http-request, http-headers

Olá gostaria de saber como eu conseguiria enviar um jwt no meu header para consumir na minha API, uma route get para pegar os usuários ( precisa de auth )

minha api para pegar os usuários:

> ```
>    app.route('/users')
>         .all(app.auth.authenticate())
>         .get((req,res)=>{
>             usersController
>                 .getAll()
>                 .then(data => {
>                     res.json(data);
>                 })
>                 .catch(error=>{
>                     console.log(error);
>                     res.status(400);
>                 });
>     })
> ```

e minha auth do jwt ( .all(app.auth.authenticate()) ) :

```
     authenticate: () => passport.authenticate('jwt', jwtConfig.session)
```

no meu front end eu não sei como vou fazer essa requisição:

```
getDate = () => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token')));
        const data = {token: sessionStorage.getItem('token')};
        const requestInfo = {
            method:'GET',
            body: JSON.stringify({data}),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }),
        };
        console.log('chegouaq');
        fetch('http://localhost:9000/users', requestInfo)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('chegouaq2');
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error("Token Invalido..")
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            return;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.setState({message: e.message})
            console.error(e);
        });
    }
```

eu sei que o get não aceita o body, mas eu não faço ideia de como mandar o meu jwt no header.

///

Meu metodo de gerar o jwt ao realizar login:

```
app.route('/login')
        .post(async (req,res)=>{

            try {
                const response = await usersControllers.signin(req.body);
                const login = response.login;
                console.log(login);
                if(login.id && login.isValid){
                    const payload = {id: login.id};
                    res.json({
                        token: jwt.sign({data:payload}, app.config.jwt.secret,{expiresIn: '60'}),
                        response
                    });
                }else{
                    console.log('entrou here');
                    res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                } 
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('entrou here');
                console.error(error.message);
                res.sendStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        })
```

e minha strategy:

```
const strategy = new Strategy(options,(payload, done) => {

        Users
        .findOne({where: payload.id})
        .then(user => {

            if(user){
                return done(null,{
                    id: user.id,
                    login: user.login
                });
            }
            return done(null,false);
        })
        .catch(error => done(error,null));

    });

    passport.use(strategy);
    return {
        initialize: () => passport.initialize(),
        authenticate: () => passport.authenticate('jwt', jwtConfig.session)
    };
}
```

Comment: Seria da mesma forma que você está passando o `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. No lugar do `Content-type` seria o nome do header que sua API espera receber o JWT e no lugar do `application/json` vai seu JWT. Seria esta sua dúvida?

Comment: Sim seria essa, você poderia responder para eu dar o voto positivo? No Caso: eu tenho essa rota:  app.route('/users') eu teria que adicionar um parametro a minha auth: .all(app.auth.authenticate()),     authenticate: () => passport.authenticate('jwt', jwtConfig.session)

Comment: Eu não sei se estou fazendo a auth do jwt de forma correta, posso editar a pergunta com o metodo que eu gero o meu jwt? Se você puder me dar alguma dica para puder melhorar no codigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da mesma forma que você indica o `Content-type` é possível indicar um `Authorization` (por exemplo):

```
// (...)
headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'minha_chave': sessionStorage.getItem('token')
})
// (...)
```

Já do lado do servidor eu não sei como está implementado mas tomando como base que o nome do header que guardará o JWT será `minha_chave` você poderia criar um middleware com o seguinte formato:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.header('minha_chave');
    jwt.verify(token, CHAVE_PRIVADA, function(err, decoded) {
        if(err) {
            res.json({ erro: true });
            return next(false);
        }

        req.session = {};
        req.session = decoded.data;
        return next();
    });
}
```

No exemplo eu usei o `jsonwebtoken` para validar o JWT.

Para utilizar este middleware em uma rota específica: `app.get('/users', meu_middleware, (req, res) => /* ...seu código... */)`.

Neste [link](https://tableless.com.br/autenticar-usuarios-com-jwt-e-passport/) tem um outro exemplo de utilização do JWT com o `passport`.

Comment: vlw mano, no caso esse mdidle irá conter a informação se o usuário possui um jwt valido ou não, ai em meu app.get('/users') eu posso utilizar o valor desse middleware para caso seja true mostrar todos os users ou false gerar um erro? Eu fiquei um pouco confuso de como utilizar esse middleware, eu postei minha strategy no passport e o meu metodo .get, você poderia dar uma olhada como eu melhoraria isso?

Comment: @gabriel no caso deste exemplo o middleware é executado antes. Caso o JWT seja inválido o código para ali mesmo e enviamos um `{ erro: true }` (exemplo). Caso o JWT seja válido, criamos uma session (exemplo também, poderia ter outro nome) `req.session = decoded.data;` e então seu código será executado de fato. Já no seu código será possível ler o payload do JWT através do `req.session` que foi alimentado no middleware.

Comment: @gabriel eu não cheguei a utilizar a `passport` :( mas pelo que li na documentação ao instanciar o `LocalStrategy` é necessário passar uma função com a seguinte assinatura `function(username, password, done)`. No seu caso esta dando algum outro erro que não seja o envio do JWT?

Comment: entendi agora mano você poderia me tirar apenas uma dúvida,  olhando pela minha rota / users depois de adicionada o middleware, e como ele vai conter o o payload do JWT, na minha rota users eu chamo a minha strategy         .all(app.auth.authenticate()), que irá chamar a minha const strategy, olhando pelo codigo eu percebo que não vou está passando esse payload por parametro em meu app.auth.authenticate() eu teria que mudar isso? Você poderia dar uma olhada nessas 2 classes que botei na pergunta:  const strategy e o meu route (/users)

Comment: Não deu apenas o error de rota, então além de passar o meu jwt eu tenho que passar o login/password? ( por curiosidade, o que você utiliza para essa parte de validar e auth o jwt?)

Comment: Pelo que eu li se tudo der certo você poderá acessar os dados do usuário através do `req.user`. Este `req.user` é indicado no `done(err, dadosUsuario)`)  dentro do `LocalStrategy`. Dê uma olhada neste exemplo: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local

Pelo que entendi sua autenticação é local, ou seja, não envolve um terceiro com o oauth. Então trafegue em seu JWT algo que identifique seu usuário, como um ID por exemplo. Dentro do seu `LocalStrategy` consulte os dados do usuário no DB e passe este objeto através do `done(null, dadosUsuario)`. Agora será possível utilizar o `req.user`

Comment: @gabriel acredito que seja este meu último comentário. Se ainda assim tiver dificuldades continuamos tentando até ficar 100%